# How to access the inner html of selector picked with .find() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a code which downloads html source from another webpage:

```
$.get
(
    'http://example.com/ex.php?something=0',
    function(response){someFunction(response)}
);
```

And then there is the function it triggers:

```
function someFunction(data)
{
    var someArray = [];
    $(data).find('.someClass').each(function(loop, item)
    {
        someArray.push(item);
    });

    $('tr:eq(1) > td:eq(0)').html(someArray[0]); //yes, I do need all the containers of class none as I'm planning to put each of them in a table cell later
}
```

So far it works correctly, but it puts `<container class="someClass">some text</container>` into the td and I just want some text extracted from it to be put there.

I have tried to go with

```
$('tr:eq(1) > td:eq(0)').html(someArray[0].html());
```

and

```
$('tr:eq(1) > td:eq(0)').html(someArray[0].contents());
```

But neither works. I've tried to google it but .contents() is the only thing I found and .html() is the only thing I could think of (normally when I have a selector selected like this `$('selector')` the method html() works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're actually replacing the cell's content with the element. If you only want its contents, just get its contents:

```
function someFunction(data)
{
    var someArray = [];
    $(data).find('.someClass').each(function(loop, item)
    {
        someArray.push($(item).contents());
    });

    $('tr:eq(1) > td:eq(0)').html(someArray[0]); //yes, I do need all the containers of class none as I'm planning to put each of them in a table cell later
}
```

`item.innerHTML` might work as well (rather than `$(item).contents()`).

---

FWIW, `map` can be useful here:

```
function someFunction(data)
{
    var someArray = $(data).find('.someClass').map(function(loop, item)
    {
        return $(item).contents();
    });

    $('tr:eq(1) > td:eq(0)').html(someArray[0]); //yes, I do need all the containers of class none as I'm planning to put each of them in a table cell later
}
```

That makes `someArray` a jQuery object, but you can still access its contents via `[0]` and such. If you want an actual array, add `.get()` to the end:

```
function someFunction(data)
{
    var someArray = $(data).find('.someClass').map(function(loop, item)
    {
        return $(item).contents();
    }).get(); // <=== Here

    $('tr:eq(1) > td:eq(0)').html(someArray[0]); //yes, I do need all the containers of class none as I'm planning to put each of them in a table cell later
}
```

Comment: I get it now ;). I just had to insert it like this $(item) not just item. Thank you very much :D.

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing the whole element into the array with

```
someArray.push(item)
```

Try replacing that with something like this:

```
someArray.push($(this).text());
```

or perhaps

```
someArray.push($(this).html());
```

Modifying your code to demonstrate the key issue on your push: http://jsfiddle.net/93Cj6/

Comment: I think my answer is more 'direct', but I also think T.J. Crowder's answer below is a *better* answer to work through - especially on map()!

Comment: You are quite right - changed reference from "jq object".